# Oracle sql - what does (+) represent here

Tags: sql, oracle

I understand that (+) can be used to represent an outer join in oracle sql.
What does the (+) in this code mean?

```
where sysdate between start_date(+) and end_date(+)
```

Comment: It means that the writer of the query is using archaic JOIN syntax and should learn how to use proper, explicit JOINs, particularly for outer joins.

Comment: How can it be archaic if it's still supported by Oracle? (joke) But it is proprietary and non-standard, and there's no reason for using it because Oracle has now supported standard OUTER JOIN syntax for many years.

Comment: The guy I learned from just left my company and he was very fond of using +'s. Really appreciate this community's help. I don't believe this is a duplicate question and having this as a standalone question might help other newbies like me looking for a solution.

Comment: @BillKarwin, there is (at least) one exception: When you like to create MATERIALIZED VIEW with FAST REFRESH then you have to use the old Oracle style for join. Oracle considers this as "lack of documentation" - not as a bug! I don't know whether this behavior changed in most recent Oracle release (i.e. 12.2)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I continue to be disappointed by Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows for an outer join to "survive" the where clause conditions. i.e. it also allows NULLs to be returned. e.g. below

```
select *
from from_table ft, outer_table ot
where sysdate between ot.start_date(+) and ot.end_date(+) 
and ft.id = ot.ft_fk(+)
```

an equivalent for that could be:

```
select *
from from_table ft
left join outer_table ot on ft.id = ot.ft_fk and sysdate between ot.start_date and ot.end_date
```

or, an equivalent for that could be:

```
select *
from from_table ft
left join outer_table ot on ft.id = ot.ft_fk
where (sysdate between ot.start_date and ot.end_date OR ot.start_date IS NULL)
```

Comment: great! thanks for your help!